# Cross-Tab Query - Date Column Sort Order

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I have an Access Cross Tab Query which uses 2 Tables (1) an Accruals Raw Data table and (2) a linked 'Month Order' table.

I am trying to sort the columns in the Cross-Tab query results in date order  using the linked 'Month Order' table which links to the Accruals Raw Data table.

However, the query is sorting the Date columns alphabetically as follows instead of in date order.

[image]

The Cross Tab query is designed as follows:

**Table 1 - Accruals Raw Data Cross Tab**

[image: **enter image description here**]

The join between the 2 tables is as follows:

[image]

The static 'Month Order' Table has the following fields

[image]

The Accruals Raw Data table has a link back to the 'Month Order' table with the following Month Order field:

[image]

I know you can enter month names in the Column Headings section below, but I don't want to use that and want to use a separate table for sorting (the 'Month Order' table below) which can be added to instead.

[image]

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple method is to sort columns on year-month, like `2019-03` from, say:

```
YearMonth: Format([Posted Date], "yyyy-mm")
```

It will never fail and is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to group a cross-tab on weeks, I found this works well:

```
YearWeek: Year([Posted Date]) & "-" & Right("0" & DatePart("ww",[Posted Date]),2)
```

The problem with weeks is that doesn't automatically add a leading zero to weeks 1 - 9 like it does for months, which results in Access sorting the weeks incorrectly:

```
1, 10, 11 ... 19, 2, 20, 21... 52, 6, 7, 8, 9.
```

The code snippet I use results in the weeks sorting as expected:

```
2023-01, 2023-02, 2023-03... 2023-50, 2023-51, 2023-52
```